# 'Unnamed VM' could not read or update the virtual machine configuration because access was denied: General access denied error (0x80070005).

Tags: hyper-v

Today I have added a host to scvmm. And later all VMs on the host are failed to restart and the following error is thrown:

> Error (12700) VMM cannot complete the host operation on the serverName
>   server because of the error: 'VMName' could not initialize. (Virtual
>   machine ID DDEA27BF-EBCA-49D6-B0BC-F89D83B1FCA4)
>
> 'VMName' could not create or access saved state file
>   D:\Hyper-V\VMName\Virtual
>   Machines\DDEA27BF-EBCA-49D6-B0BC-F89D83B1FCA4\DDEA27BF-EBCA-49D6-B0BC-F89D83B1FCA4.vsv. (Virtual machine ID DDEA27BF-EBCA-49D6-B0BC-F89D83B1FCA4) Unknown
>   error (0x8006)
>
> Recommended Action Resolve the host issue and then try the operation
>   again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later we follow the ["Hyper-V virtual machine may not start, and you receive a “‘General access denied error’ (0x80070005)” error message"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2249906) to successfully resolve the issue.

Solution is to grant each VM to access its VM files and directories.

```
icacls <Path of .vhd or .avhd file> /grant "NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\<Virtual Machine ID from step 1>":(F)
```

To grant permission to virtual machine folder and its children:

```
icacls "D:\Hyper-V\Virtual Machine" /grant "NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\DDEA27BF-EBCA-49D6-B0BC-F89D83B1FCA4":(OI)(CI)F
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on start-up of my VM after I had changed out a drive on my server. The new drive had the same letter assigned as the previous drive and all the files had been copied over, including my VM folder that contained the .vhd file. I executed the `icacls` command as given in [Amitabha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20607550/649497), but this did not resolve the issue for me.

I then read somewhere that the group `Authenticated Users` should have full access to the folder containing the virtual machine configuration files. So I add the security group `Authenticated Users` in the `security` tab of my `VM` folder properties and gave this group `full control` rights. After doing this my VM started correctly.